# Add root element attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm serializing a class like below

```
 XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
 namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<student>), new XmlRootAttribute("Response"));
 XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
 serializer1.Serialize(xmlWriter, ls, namespaces);
 sw.ToString()
```

The result string below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Response><student><name>xxx</name></student></Response>
```

but, How can i add an attribute to the root element(Response)? 
like below one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Response status="1"><student><name>xxx</name></student></Response>
```

Comment: Where is that `1` taken from? Is it always `1`?

Comment: not always 1. it may be 1 or 0. I'm setting 1 if no error else 0

Answer (score 3):

You just need to mark that property of the class with XmlAttribute, i.e.

```
class MyClass{
[XmlAttribute("status")]
public string ErrorStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Just realised you are serializing the list directly.  Put your list inside a parent class, Response, and add the above attribute to this Response class, then serialise the Response object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for which class? you mean student?

Comment: sorry,not working. will it work if remove namespace? and also i'm modifying root element.

Comment: How is it not working, throwing an error or not what you expect?  The namespace shouldn't matter

Comment: Are you using `XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));` where response is MyClass in the above example

Answer (score 1):

You can create another object that contains the list, and then create a property to add the attribute to the root node.

The trick is to preface the list in this new class with an explicit type assignment to the Student type to avoid having your list nested within another parent node.

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Response")]    
public class ResponseObject
{
    [XmlAttribute("status")]        
    public string file { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Student", Type = typeof(Student))]
    public List<Student> studentList { get; set; }
}
```

Your code would then look like the following

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseObject));
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

//Creating new object and assign the existing list and status
ResponseObject resp = new ResponseObject();
resp.studentList = ls;
resp.status = 1;

//Serialize with the new object
serializer1.Serialize(xmlWriter, resp, namespaces);
sw.ToString()
```